# How to understand Script Editor dictionaries?

Tags: applescript, desktop

I found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151435/how-to-programmatically-get-the-path-to-the-wallpaper-on-the-active-desktop) an interesting example of Apple script commands such, for instance,

```
tell application "System Events" to get properties of every desktop
```

and I would like to understand, where these commands are documented. I found the explanation for the `tell` command, and I understand that we have to use the "Systems Events" app for this task. I even discovered the "Script Editor" app and inside it, I opened the Dictionary for "System Events", and find plenty of definitions, which are likely methods we can invoke on the "System Events" object.

However, I did not find any  explanation of the keywords `get` or `every` in the above command. Using the Search field and entering "get" and "every" did not bring up anything useful. Perhaps they are some keywords with a predefined meaning.

I could type "desktop" in the search field, and find as explanation something like this (abbreviated):

> desktop n : desktop picture settings
> elements
> contained by application.
> properties

> name (text, r/o) : name of the desktop

> id (integer, r/o) : unique identifier of the desktop
> ....

My guess is that 'desktop' is the instance of some object, which in turn is contained inside another object of class application, and that we can send it methods such as `name` or `id`. However, I don't see any relationship to the `tell application` command above, and how we could logically conclude from this Dictionary explanation that this command would magically show us information about the desktops.

My programming background is Ruby/Python/Perl/C++/zsh and a bit of Haskell and Java, and I thought I would be able to understand library references of other languages somehow, but this one is too much for me...

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [**AppleScript Keywords**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_keywords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH222-SW2) in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1), as well as perusing the entire *guide* itself.

> get an AppleScript command—see [get](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW56)

> **get**
>
> Evaluates an object specifier and returns the result.

> every specifies every object in a container—see [Every](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-BBCJFIIH) reference form

> **Every**
>
> Specifies every object of a particular class in a container.

**Note:**  There is additional information for each that was not copied to they answer.